# Is there a discrepancy in Turn A Gundam timeline?

Tags: chronology, mobile-suit-gundam

I have read that Tomino stated that Turn A Gundam is supposed to be set 500 years before Gundam Reconguista in G (which itself was stated to take place around 1000 years after UC).

Here's what I don't understand: it is stated in official materials that Turn A series take place in the year 2343 of Correct Century and Correct Century according to official timeline only started at the very end of Black history period (which I believe is the end of UC era).

But how can this be? If Gundam Reconguista in G is supposed to take place 1,000 years after UC ended wouldn't that overlap with Turn A timeline placement? And there's no way that CC can be considered taken place 500 years after UC, since the events in Turn A were in the year 2343, which implies that at least 2343 years have passed since UC calendar was in use.

Did I miss anything? Was there an official explanation from Sunrise regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Where Bandai and Tomino disagree, Tomino is wrong. Period. The fact is that many Gundam series were created without Tomino, and so his say on things is ultimately irrelevant. Bandai's official timeline has Turn A taking place 7000 years after UC, and G-Reco 1000 years after UC. Tomino might have intended G-Reco to be after Turn A, but Bandai's timeline trumps Tomino's.

And remember that Tomino likes to fudge canon a lot. All of his novelizations of his Gundam works change the endings, sometimes significantly, and don't forget that he wrote and directed the Zeta movies, which don't fit at all into the established canon of UC. Considering how little attention Bandai gives to G-Reco (not a single 1/100, not even for the main suit...) I think it's safe to place it as "non-canon."

Comment: This seems like a logical answer to me! :)

Answer (score -1):

It is likely that the 2343 years passed in the Correct Century are not equivalent to one year of our current calendar system. Furthermore, this could be applied to any of shows that use an alternative calendar system.

It is also possible that Tomino is just trolling the entire community, but I think it is probably best to stick to calendar system differences being the most likely answer to a lot of the discrepancies within the Gundam timeline.

(EDIT: Tomino has also stated that the 'official' timeline information that is released by Bandai is wrong. Though with this all you can either believe Tomino's take or Sunrise/Bandai's until a more definitive answer comes out.)

Comment: Bandai has the ultimate say on the series though. Tomino himself also creates conflicting timelines a lot in his Gundam-related works.

Answer (score -1):

That's where you're wrong. G Reco doesn't take place a thousand years after Universal Century. It takes place thousands of years after Universal Century. Hell, Turn A took 8000 years after Universal Century.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It's not clear if you're addressing the question here; who is wrong?  If this is intended as a comment on the question or another answer, please don't post it as an answer.  (You might want to read [answer].)  Also, if this is intended as an answer, it would work a lot better if you could provide a source for the 8000 years figure, and the relationship with G Reco.

Comment: If you're referring to [guest12345678's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/165854/76048), they claim it's "Bandai's official timeline". Can you provide any evidence that this *isn't* their official timeline?